# Qt sqlite deploy exe

Tags: qt, sqlite, deployment

I have a Qt `.exe` built from Visual Studio 2005 (after taking the `.cpp`, `.h`, `.moc`, ui_ files)

I have done some simple QSqlite queries. It works fine in my development pc. But in another pc it crashes for the line below:

```
QSqlDatabase mSqlDb
```

How can I run the `.exe` so that it can interact with `sqlite` on another PC? [Other GUI application run just fine.]

What things are necessary to deploy a sqlite-qt application?

Answer (score 6):

I'd give you a better answer, but you tend to not accept answers, so here is a link to the documentation: [Deploying an Application on Windows - Qt Plugins](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/deployment-windows.html#qt-plugins) :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Qt with shared libraries (standard compiled Qt download is Qt with shared libraries), you must follow this 2 easy steps:

1) tell QtCore to seach for plugins in 'your_directory' 
(use 'qApp->addLibraryPath(".")' to point into same directory, where your binary shall stay)

2) create subdirectory 'sqldrivers' in 'your_directory' and copy 'qsqlite4.dll' plugin in it
(qsqlite4.dll plugin is in $$QT_DIR/plugins/sqldrivers/ directory)

Answer (score 1):

I've just successfully compiled a static version (you have to compile it statically to avoid dependency problems) of a program that uses qt sqlite library with a MinGw compiler (bundled with Qt).
Here are the steps that I used:

1. Open command line and run c:\\bin\qtenv.bat
2. The go to c:\\qt\
3. and run this: "configure -static -release -nomake demo -nomake examples -no-exceptions -qt-sql-sqlite"
4. Then run this: "mingw32-make src-sub"
5. *If you get some "phonon" error during compilation, then run "mingw32-make confclean" and then add "-no-phonon" parameter to command on 3. step and continue from there*
6. Wait for few hours
7. Go to your project folder
8. Run "qmake"
9. Run "mingw32-make"
10. Check the release folder, it should work

Good luck...